# .NET Core Console App services.AddAutofac() Not Working

Tags: .net-core, console-application, autofac, autofac-configuration

I am attempting to use Autofac with a .NET Core console application using the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` packages but the load methods inside my modules never get invoked and leads to `Program` being null during resolution. I would have expected them to load either when I called the `AddAutofac()` extension method or when the service provider was built.

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class Startup
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {               
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddAutofac(builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(new MyFirstModule(configuration));
            builder.RegisterModule(new MySecondModule(configuration));
        });

        using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
        {
            var program = serviceProvider.GetService<Program>();
            program.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: I'm not sure what other details you would be referring to? The .NET Core service container configuration seems pretty common but I have never done it outside of a WebApi project where there is no IWebHostingEnvironment.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/issues/12), when the `AddAutofac` method was added to the documentation, it was also split between [ASP.NET Core](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) and [.NET Core](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html). Apparently, `AddAutofac` is specific to ASP.NET Core applications (hence the different documents).

For [console applications](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html), the registration should look like:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class Startup
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {               
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Once you've registered everything in the ServiceCollection, call
        // Populate to bring those registrations into Autofac. This is
        // just like a foreach over the list of things in the collection
        // to add them to Autofac.
        containerBuilder.Populate(services);

        // Make your Autofac registrations. Order is important!
        // If you make them BEFORE you call Populate, then the
        // registrations in the ServiceCollection will override Autofac
        // registrations; if you make them AFTER Populate, the Autofac
        // registrations will override. You can make registrations
        // before or after Populate, however you choose.
        builder.RegisterModule(new MyFirstModule(configuration));
        builder.RegisterModule(new MySecondModule(configuration));

        // Creating a new AutofacServiceProvider makes the container
        // available to your app using the Microsoft IServiceProvider
        // interface so you can use those abstractions rather than
        // binding directly to Autofac.
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();
        var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);

        var program = serviceProvider.GetService<Program>();
        program.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entry point should be `Program.cs` in a dotnet core application. Also I am not sure why do you have a private Main method. But regardless, please follow these steps

Autofac documentation says that:

> You don’t have to use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. If you
>   aren’t writing a .NET Core app that requires it or if you’re not using
>   any of the DI extensions provided by other libraries you can consume
>   Autofac directly.

You can actually use Autofac without extensions. See a very basic example of a dotnet core console application. Make sure you install a nuGet package Autofac (current version 4.8.1)

We can have an interface:

```
public interface IPrintService
{
    void Print();
}
```

And an implementation of this interface.

```
public class PrintService
    : IPrintService
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a print service injected");
    }
}
```

then we can have, for example, a class where we inject a `IPrintService` through its constructor

```
public class Client
{
    public Client(IPrintService printService)
    {
        printService.Print();
    }
}
```

And finally, in the main console program we can configure Autofac and register the services. Notice that I have decided to autoActivate a `Client` instance just to illustrate an example and prove that Autofac is injecting the desired implementation.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConfigureIoCc();
        Console.WriteLine("Using Autofac");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IContainer ConfigureIoCc()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder
            .RegisterType<PrintService>()
            .As<IPrintService>();

        builder
            .RegisterType<Client>()
            .AsSelf()
            .AutoActivate(); //to automatically instantiate it

        var container = builder.Build();
        return container;
    }
}
```